# What is an internal space (Tetrad formalism for GR)

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

**Context**: I'm reading about tetrad formalism in General Relativity. Thus, a tetrad is something as $e_I=e^\mu_I\partial_\mu$ where the greek indices are related to a chart and the Latin indice is related to internal space $\mathbb{R}^4$ (Minkowski space).

**Question**: What would be (or where can I find) a formal definition of what an internal space is?

**Edit** Folowing [Bojowald](https://books.google.com.br/books?hl=pt-BR&lr=&id=qGoLVnjDewUC&oi=fnd&pg=PR5&dq=canonical%20gravity%20bojowald&ots=IgEmhHkzE5&sig=-KWBbZZdF_yqOLciNK9K4mI0Udg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=canonical%20gravity%20bojowald&f=false): Canonical Gravity; at page 84 he said:

"We define a space-time tetrad as a set of fours vectors field $e^a_I$, labeled by an additional index $I$ taking the values $0,1,2,3$, such that they provide an orthonormal basis of the tangente space at each point:
\begin{equation}
g_{ab}e^a_Ie^b_J=\eta_{IJ}
\end{equation}

with the Minkowski metric $\eta_{IJ}$. Thus $e^a_0$ is timelike while $e^a_1$, $e^a_2$ and $e^a_3$ are spacelike.

We may view the label I simply as an index to distinguish the vector fields, but a more powerful interpretation is to think of $e^a_I$ I as a double-vector field: a vector field on the tangent bundle of space-time taking values in Minkowski space.

With a 1-form $\omega_a$, $e^a_I \omega_a$ assigns to every point in space-time a covector in Minkowski space. In this context, one often thinks of space-time as equipped with two independent vectorial structures: its tangent space as well as an independent set of Minkowski spaces, one attached to each point.

Minkowski space in this context is called an **internal vector space**, and $e^a_I \omega_a$ of the above example an internal vector field. A manifold with a copy of the same vector space attached to each point is called a vector bundle..."

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question as it stands. The phrase "internal space" is not sufficiently standard; it seems to be part of the way your book chooses to address a distinction between ways of mapping spacetime. So we would need more information about the rest of the book. Perhaps it will become clearer as you read.

Comment: I will edit the question to give more information.

Comment: Internal space is a fibre of a fibre bundle over spacetime that is not a *natural bundle* . What are referred to as "spacetime degrees of freedom" as opposed to "internal degrees of freedom" (which live in the internal spaces) are fibres of natural bundles.

Comment: @BenceRacskó  Is that always the case???  In the the reduction of the frame bundle to the orthonormal frame bundle (an principal $SO(1,3)$ bundle) like in the tetrad formulation $SO(1,3)$ is usually referred to as an internal gauge group (associated with an internal symmetry) , but it stems from a natural bundle (i.e. the frame bundle).  I would also steer the curious to the paper "internal, external, and generalized symmetries" by anderson, kamran, and olver.  They specifically study "internal symmetries" associated with reductions of jet bundles which by construction are natural bundles.

Comment: @AndrewSteane  I think by internal space he's referring to the fibre, and in this context the one corresponding to the tangent bundle of spacetime?